# Using Cypress, can we do an assert with test results

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I'd like to write something to the log based on test results. for example, if there are 0 tests passing, we could write something to the log or if there are more than 1 tests that are skipped

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cypress [after run api](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api#Syntax) for this. Since this is still an experimental feature you have to mention in your `cypress.json`

```
experimentalInteractiveRunEvents: true
```

And then in your `cypress/plugins/index.js` file you can write:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('after:run', (results) => {
        if (results.totalPassed == 0) {
            console.log('Print something')
        } else if (results.totalPassed > 0) {
            console.log('Print something')
        }
    })
}
```

Your should `cypress/plugins/index.js` look like:

```
//For cucumber integration 
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

//For Image Snapshot Plugin
const {
    addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin,
} = require('cypress-image-snapshot/plugin');

//For cypress retry plugin
require('cypress-plugin-retries')

module.exports = (on, config) => {

    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber()); //For cypress cucumber preprocessor

    addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin(on); //For Image Snapshot Plugin

    require('cypress-plugin-retries/lib/plugin')(on); //For cypress retry plugin

    on('after:run', (results) => {   //after run event
        if (results.totalPassed == 0) {
            console.log('Print something')
        } else if (results.totalPassed > 0) {
            console.log('Print something')
        }
    });

}
```

One thing to remember is This code is part of the plugins file and thus executes in the Node environment so you cannot call Cypress or cy commands in this file.

These are other properties from the result object which you can also use:

```
// results will look something like this when run via `cypress run`:
// {
//   totalDuration: 81,
//   totalSuites: 0,
//   totalTests: 1,
//   totalFailed: 0,
//   totalPassed: 1,
//   totalPending: 0,
//   totalSkipped: 0,
//   browserName: 'electron',
//   browserVersion: '59.0.3071.115',
//   osName: 'darwin',
//   osVersion: '16.7.0',
//   cypressVersion: '3.1.0',
//   config: {
//     projectId: '1qv3w7',
//     baseUrl: 'http://example.com',
//     viewportWidth: 1000,
//     viewportHeight: 660,
//     // ... more properties...
//   }
//   // ... more properties...
//   }
```

Comment: Hey, I'm getting this error `npx cypress run --spec cypress/integration/*.js --env tags=uidfdffd

The following validation error was thrown by your plugins file (`C:\Repos\visual-regression-template\cypress\plugins\index.js`).

 Error: You must pass a valid event name when registering a plugin.

You passed: `after:run`

The following are valid events:
- file:preprocessor
- before:browser:launch
- task
- after:screenshot`

Comment: Can you post your `cypress/plugins/index.js` file ? I have updated one change, can you try that changed `after:run` to `test:after:run`.

Comment: Sure thing:. . . . . . . .. module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    log(message) {
      console.log(message)
       return null
    },
  })
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
  addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin(on, config)
  require('cypress-plugin-retries/lib/plugin')(on)

  on('test:after:run', (results) => {
    if (results.totalPassed == 0) {
        console.log('Print something')
    } else if (results.totalPassed > 0) {
        console.log('Print something')
    }
})
}

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try now. Also don't forget to make the changes to `cypress.json` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I have included this already,   "experimentalInteractiveRunEvents": true. I'll check your new answer now

Comment: ok, I fixed a previous error re the file not being found, however I'm still getting `` The following validation error was thrown by your plugins file (`C:\Repos\visual-regression-template\cypress\plugins\index.js`). You passed: `after:run``... Any other suggestions?